# Mass convert audio files to a specified bitrate, but only if their bitrate is higher than that bitrate using ffmpeg

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of audio files in a directory some are 128Kbps , some are higher.

I want to convert the ones with a bitrate higher than 128Kbps to 128Kbps to save space.
I tried writing a shell script to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="*.mp3"

for F in $FILES

do
newname=`basename "$F" -smaller.mp3`
ffmpeg -i "$F" -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 "$newname.mp3"

done
```

But it also converts files that are already 128Kbps and therefore would take a lot more time to complete.

How could I check if a file`s bitrate is higher than 128Kbps and convert it down to 128Kbps only if so.

Comment: Do you have the `file` command?

Answer (score 4):

Using `ffprobe`

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.mp3
do
    brate=$(ffprobe "$file" |& grep -Eo 'bitrate: [0-9]+' | cut -d' ' -f2)
    if [[ "$brate" -gt 128 ]]
    then
        newname=$(basename "$file" -smaller.mp3)
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 "${newname}.mp3"
    fi
done
```